# OnClick Event doesn't work in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replicate this simple JavaScript in a Chrome extension, but nothing is working. I understand that I can't use inline script, so I know exactly what the problem is, but I've been all over this site and I can't find a solution.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(user)
    {
        var location='https://www.stackoverflow.com/';

        window.location = location+user;
    }

function join_ym()
{
var thing1 = document.getElementById('thing1').value;
var thing2 = document.getElementById('thing2').value;
document.getElementById('joint').value = 'this-'+thing1+'-then-this-'+thing2;
javascript:redirect(document.getElementById('joint').value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>First Thing:<input type="text" id="thing1" /></p>
<p>Second Thing:<input type="text" id="thing2" /></p>
<input type="hidden" id="joint">
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="join_ym();">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In this example there are two text boxes, so if you were to type "thing" into both, and click go you would be taken to: https://stackoverflow.com/this-thing-then-this-thing. I think the issue is specifically with the onclick event, unless input type is also an issue. I've looked through examples from the Content Security Policy, and examples from this site, but nothing has worked. All I need to know is what goes in the .js and what goes in the .html files. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right, inline script is not allowed. You'll need to move all your script into a separate file, e.g. `script.js`, and then reference that with a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You'll likely need to set the button's onclick in your script as well, e.g.

```
document.querySelector('button[value=go]').onclick = join_ym;
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use addEventListener**

*html:*

```
<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

*script.js:*

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(){
  console.log('asd');
}
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly it will work !